# Blender red material and transparent

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

[image]

My mesh is red and transparent, I do not know what to do to return it to the normal state

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image that shows the materials you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Your viewport material's alpha is not set to 1, that's why your object is semi-transparent. Click on the Color field and set the Alpha to 1.

[image]

The red color might come from backfaces. You can either recalculate normals with SHIFT + N or deactivate it in the overlays :

[image]